# 1111. appearing after print sequence - php

Tags: php

Morning,

I have some code that takes a string of shoe sizes, explodes it and then puts it in a table. The code works perfectly and the info is displayed correctly on the page but after the table there is always a few 1's after the table. I'm really confused about this.

So the table looks like this (in columns of three on the webpage)

Available in the following sizes:
3           4            5
6           9            10

111

Here's the Codes, for the purpose of the example $x = 3|4|6|10|9

```
function get_sizes_pipe($x) {

$counter = 0;
$splits = explode("|",$x);
asort($splits);

$x = print "<table class='greentable'>";

$x .= print "<thead><tr><th scope='col' colspan='3' abbr='Starter'>Available in the following sizes:</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";

foreach ($splits as $split) {
    $entry = print "<td>".$split."</td>";

    if($counter == 2){
        $entry .= print "</tr><tr>";
        $counter =0;
    } else {

    $counter++;

    }

}

if($counter == 1){
    $entry .= print "<td></td><td></td>";
}elseif ($counter == 2) {
    $entry .= print "<td></td>";
}

$x.= $entry;

$x.= print "</tr></tbody></table>";

return $x;

}
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: `print` function returns some value.

Comment: do not use print you are already appending it to $x just echo $x;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:do not use print you are already appending it to `$x` just `echo $x;`

```
 <?php
function get_sizes_pipe($x) {

$counter = 0;
$splits = explode("|",$x);
asort($splits);

$x =  "<table class='greentable'>";

$x .= "<thead><tr><th scope='col' colspan='3' abbr='Starter'>Available in the following sizes:</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";

foreach ($splits as $split) {
    $entry .= "<td>".$split."</td>";//use . to concate here

    if($counter == 2){
        $entry .= "</tr><tr>";
        $counter =0;
    } else {

    $counter++;

    }

}

if($counter == 1){
    $entry .="<td></td><td></td>";
}elseif ($counter == 2) {
    $entry .=  "<td></td>";
}

$x.= $entry;

$x.="</tr></tbody></table>";

echo $x;

}

get_sizes_pipe("1|2|3|4");
```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly! Why do you concate the first entry?

Comment: i just gave the idea you can change accordingly.

Comment: now as you know print return true/1 so better use echo to display strings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why do you concatenate `print` with some variable, but you should know that function `print` returns `1` (always) as a result of execution, so doing

```
$x .= print 'some value';
```

is the same as

```
print 'some value';
$x .= 1;
```

Comment: I'm self-taught in php, I knew it had something to do with the print but I didn't know that it always returns a value, thanks for the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using string concatenation ( which becomes inefficient with large strings ) add html strings to an array and return the flattened html from your function.

```
function get_sizes_pipe($x) {
    $counter = 0;
    $splits = explode("|",$x);
    asort( $splits );

    $html=array();

    $html[]="
        <table class='greentable'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope='col' colspan='3' abbr='Starter'>Available in the following sizes:</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>";

    foreach( $splits as $split ) {
        $html[]="<td>".$split."</td>";
        if( $counter == 2 ){
            $html[]="</tr><tr>";
            $counter=0;
        } else {
            $counter++;
        }

    }

    $html[]=( $counter == 1 ) ? "<td></td><td></td>" : "<td></td>";
    $html[]="
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>";

    return implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
}

/* call your function with whatever value of `$x` you need */
echo get_sizes_pipe( $what_is_x );
```